# How to select the language (for captions) in a rmarkdown document

Tags: r-markdown

Is there a way to select the language for Rmarkdown? For example, I'm writing an assignment in portuguese, but table captions will come off as `Table 1: something.`

In latex files you can just add `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}`. Is there an equivalent option for `rmarkdown`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the TeX SE site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown.

You can just include packages with a header-includes argument.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
output:
    pdf_document
---
```